# laravel named route in ajax url is not interpreted

Tags: ajax, laravel

when I do this ajax call :

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '{{ route("showposts") }}',
        type: 'GET',
       
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)

        }
    });
```

the url request is sent like this :

`http://127.0.0.1/bao/public/%7B%7B%20route(%22showposts%22)%20%7D%7D`

but the url I want is :

`http://127.0.0.1/bao/public/postes`

this what my route looks like :

```
Route::get('/postes', 'HomeController@showPosts')->name('showposts');
```

#### Note :

when I put the URI hard coded in ajax url it work fine

Comment: Is that script inside a blade template?

Comment: the script I in this path public/js/home/dashboard.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade is the simple, yet powerful templating engine provided with Laravel. Unlike other popular PHP templating engines, Blade does not restrict you from using plain PHP code in your views. In fact, all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified, meaning Blade adds essentially zero overhead to your application. Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file extension and are typically stored in the `resources/views` directory.

**You can't use that syntax in a javascript file**, it just won't work. You have to move the script to a blade file.

Comment: you're right !! so there is no way to separate ajax from views to make code a bit modulare in this case ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to do it with the static routes, without using any of the blade syntax. You can use a package like https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy if necessary.